# type of template available in Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I am installing vue.js by CLI, and there i have found the command such as

**vue init template-name project-name**

Thus, I want to know that what are these templates and how many of these are there which will be appropriate for me?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i looked up and researched and found that there are, different versions for templates in Vue, if you are using it by Cli.
Templates are such as:-

1. webpack
2. webpack-simple
3. pwa
4. simple
5. browserify
6. browserify-simple

in which webpack is used mostly. since it provides some css extraction and more features too

Answer (score 0):

Generally developers who are new to any framework, mainly use webpack-simple that sets up all things for them regarding gulp, eslintrc and much more files.

Comment: Does webpack not do it? @Meet

Comment: @SiddharthChoudhary It does but beginners to this type of environment go with wepack simple especially when migrating to new framework

Comment: also if do you know that how can i mix a vue with node js. As i am following this tutorial https://appdividend.com/2017/08/04/vuejs-nodejs-tutorial/ , but what i have done is i created vue js project through CLI  and now i am running the nodejs in this project , but now what is occuring is that i am trying to run nodemon but nodemon is not being detected as a command

Comment: see either you can use express to run a server or maybe use node to run server. But here webpack has its setup as `npm run dev` which will run on localhost. So basically if you use node.js for running server than its waste of using in it. Instead you can  use it for event emiiters, file read write, middleware,etc. @SiddharthChoudhary